# Uso de "Cada" sin nada detrás

Tags: uso-de-palabras, dialectos

Visto en Facebook:

> Cada que compartes esta imagen...

¿Es correcto este uso de la palabra "Cada", sin la palabra "vez" a continuación?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sí, se puede, pero ha caído en gran desuso.

[Este artículo](https://books.google.com/books?id=JB7RFgYeBEkC&pg=PA9&dq=%22cada%20que%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBGoVChMIw_ikmsGxyAIVx5iACh05QQ0X#v=onepage&q=%22cada%20que%22&f=false) que menciona el origen del uso — no es simplemente *cada vez que* sin la palabra *vez*, la forma *cada vez que* vino después.  También es notado en [otro libro de gramática](https://books.google.com/books?id=Zt2HOq1OG7kC&pg=PA1438&dq=%22cada%20que%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBGoVChMIr4-4h8KxyAIVCqGACh3YlABO#v=onepage&q=%22cada%20que%22&f=false).

La locución registra [usos académicos](https://books.google.com/books?id=AVOWlKtiNMIC&pg=PA48&dq=%22cada%20que%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CF8Q6AEwCWoVChMIw_ikmsGxyAIVx5iACh05QQ0X#v=onepage&q=%22cada%20que%22&f=false) en 2000 y se evidencia en contextos más informales [en 2015](https://books.google.com/books?id=8wLnCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT46&dq=%22cada%20que%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBmoVChMIr4-4h8KxyAIVCqGACh3YlABO#v=onepage&q=%22cada%20que%22&f=false).

Según Google N-Grams, podemos ver que es el principio del siglo XVIII cuando *cada vez que* empezó a usarse con muchísimas más frecuencia.

[image: Graph showing increasing use of cada_vez_que and decreasing use of cada_que]

No obstante, la forma sigue registrada en el DRAE, incluso en la 23.<sup>a</sup> edición, por lo que podemos asegurarnos de que no se considera tan en desuso que se lo deba censurar.

> **cada<sup>2</sup>**
> **~ que**. **1.** *loc. adv.* Siempre que, o **cada** vez que.

Y sobre el tema, dice la RAE lo siguiente en su *Gramática* (§15.7h):

> La omisión del sustantivo puede darse también en grupos nominales encabezados por otros determinantes y cuantificadores, como en *Ahora, cuéntame una de piratas* (Fuentes, *Región*), donde se sobrentiende *historia* o *película*. En el español preclásico era frecuente omitir el sustantivo *vez* entre el distributivo *cada* y la oración de relativo que lo sigue, como en *Cada que vuestro nombre yo le estó deziendo, / otéame e sospira e está comediendo* (Arcipreste Hita, *Buen Amor*).  Este uso se perdió en el español europeo, pero pervive en el español coloquial mexicano, así como en parte de las áreas centroamericana, caribeña y andina:
>
> *Cada que* nos encontrábamos, le hablaba de ti a la señorita Hortensia (Prada Oropeza, *Hora*); Desde hace dos años tomamos café *cada que* viene al puerto (Aguilar Camín, *Golfo*); *Cada que* veo esta nave pienso que Dios existe (María, *Fábrica*)

Esta información se repite en §19.9d (donde dice que sería una omisión de *vez* u *ocasión*, aunque el primer artículo enlazado dice que no es meramente una omisión, sino una construcción propia).

Comment: ¡Fantástica investigación! Cuando estuve buscando encontré muchos usos informales, parece como que haya quedado reducido a algún dialecto.

Comment: Esta respuesta arroja mucha más luz sobre la pregunta que la originalmente aceptada.

Answer (score 4):

No, no es correcto. Comprueba los usos de ["cada"](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=w9DN5SNTqDXX2x3yywiE) en la web de la RAE.

`Cada` suele funcionar como adjetivo, por lo que necesita algo a lo que adjetivar y en esa frase no lo hay. Lo más probable es que sea un error y haya una palabra perdida. Lo que tendría sentido, como bien adivinas, sería

> Cada **vez** que compartes esta imagen...